# Sanitizing base64 image gives changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity

Tags: angular, base64, angular-dom-sanitizer

I'm trying to render an image which I have converted to base64

```
data:image/vnd.microsoft.icon;base64,AAABAAIAICAAA.....
```

Now, whatever I do, I always get

```
{
     changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: 'data:image/vnd.micr.....
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mczd2g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

So, in my search people suggest to use `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` or `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl`, but both produce the same result. I've also seen people suggesting

```
<img src="{{base64}}">
```

But this is no different than `<img [src]="....">`, it produces

```
<img src="unsafe:data:image/vnd.microsoft.icon;base64,AAABA....">
```

(Note the `unsafe` at the beginning)

And I have seen suggestions to use

```
<img [src]="safeUrl.changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity">
```

But this doesn't feel right.

Any suggestion how to properly render this base64 image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened up your demo and there's a few things that jump out at me

1. Your base 64 is double quoted: `'"..."'` so you should remove the `"`'s or the `'`'s.
2. You're seeing `{ changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity: ... }` because you have `console.log(this.url)`
3. Your dom should look like this: `<img [src]="url" />`

Making all 3 of those changes shows the image correctly and there's nothing in the errors/etc...: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uxhrr2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @jfriend00 no worries. I deleted my answer, not the question. Just clicked on it and it says:

"This post is hidden. It was deleted 1 hour ago by the post author."